# Docker WSL container scripts suddenly stopped working

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I reinstalled my gitlab folder on the WSL UBUNTU, which I have done several times before, and backend container suddenly stopped working, typing this in logs:
/usr/bin/env: ‘python\r’: No such file or directory

Then I tried reinstalling the image, and it typed this:
/usr/bin/env: ‘sh\r’: No such file or directory
When I tried reinstalling all of the containers in composter, one another container (frontend) turned off with the same problem (:)

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your file has Windows line endings, which are \r\n. You need to change this to \n. Here's a guide on how to do this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/803162/how-to-change-windows-line-ending-to-unix-version